# Change url of single page wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

marketing team wants to do a mobile only split test on analytics and needs the general URL on that single page to have a m.mytest.com/split instead of the one that shares with the whole site www.mytest.com/split and that only can be viewed on mobile

Anyone knows of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify that in your **.htaccess** document in your Wordpress root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^newUrl$ /?old-page=999 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`newUrl` is your **new link**

`/?old-page=999` is your **old link**

Comment: Was just going to post this lol, yes a URL Redirect form a web-server directive which I would assume be Apache, is def the best approach. There are other ways but don't bother this is straightforward and simplest with out huge site construct modification.

Comment: in some cases you have to set `AllowOverride` to `All` in your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`  file

Comment: and lets not forget to make sure the module - `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

ok, so just to be clear, my new url would be "m.mytest.com/split" and my old "www.mytest.com/split"?

I'm asking for clarification because I thought this was to rewrite the slug and not the entire url